# How to create bootable flash for "efi-shell"

Tags: shell, boot, uefi

Current Intel server chipsets include a built-in "efi-shell" which appears to basically be a simplified 'NIX with a command set suitable for manipulating some nifty UEFI boot options.

It is also the case that some of Intel's firmware upgrade tools now require "efi-shell" to run.

Sadly, I do not have a server chipset even though this board does support UEFI booting.

The efi-shell can be downloaded from http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/efi-shell. However, I can find no bootable ISO or any other form of bootable image.

I have attempted to make a bootable flash with `unetbootin` with no success.

Any thoughts on how I might make a copy of efi-shell bootable so I can run the Intel firmware upgrade on my RAID card?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just drop [this binary](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/UDK2018/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi?raw=true) into that flash drive FAT's root directory (or maybe `EFI/BOOT/` subdirectory, depends IIRC) under the name of `shellx64.efi`, or get yourself a copy of [refind usbflash image](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) which would also serve as a decent boot manager.

Comment: PS: I make weekly http://en.altlinux.org/rescue images which include EFI shell, memtest86 and refind, all of those signed with ALT cert stuffed into MS-signed shim in the image -- maybe you'll find those handy, and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The binary link is broken, it's supposedly now lives [here](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/UDK2018/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi?raw=true). And it works for me. But I'm not too familiar with the topic to suggest it for everyone.